# Is there a way to check the quality of a hash function?

Tags: security, hash, md5, sha256, sha1

Hash functions utilize the avalanche effect, i.e. if I slightly change the input I'll get a output completely different. So when I say the quality I mean, is there a way to check how "big" this difference is mathematically?

I thought it would make sense to think of the two hash outputs as vectors and calculate their euclidean distance using their bytes. As an example, in sha1 we have hashes with 20 bytes, so I would take each pair of bytes from the first and second output and apply them to the euclidean distance formula. I'm not sure the result I get from this has anything to do with the security of the function.

Comment: I don't think I've ever seen anyone try to test for something like this. Either a hash is the same or it is different-- there is no magnitude to the difference, and no point in trying to measure it, as far as I know.

Comment: You might get more answers at https://crypto.stackexchange.com/